# Angular 2 Tour of Heroes, Step 7 error

Tags: angularjs, angular

I looked through the forums, but couldn't find anything relevant.

I just started the tutorial 3 days ago, got to Step 7, and when I add the `InMemoryWebApiModule` to the mix (as detailed in the steps), I get this error:

[image]

All of my config files are directly from what was provided in the tutorial, but I'll provide them here anyway.

Any ideas as to what's going on?

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-quickstart",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "tsc && concurrently \"tsc -w\" \"lite-server\" ",
    "lite": "lite-server",
    "tsc": "tsc",
    "tsc:w": "tsc -w"
  },
  "licenses": [
    {
      "type": "MIT",
      "url": "https://github.com/angular/angular.io/blob/master/LICENSE"
    }
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/compiler": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/core": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/forms": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/http": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~2.1.1",
    "@angular/router": "~3.1.1",
    "@angular/upgrade": "~2.1.1",
    "angular-in-memory-web-api": "~0.1.13",
    "bootstrap": "^3.3.7",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.8",
    "rxjs": "5.0.0-beta.12",
    "systemjs": "0.19.39",
    "zone.js": "^0.6.25"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/core-js": "^0.9.34",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.45",
    "concurrently": "^3.0.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.2.2",
    "typescript": "^2.0.3"
  }
}
```

Here is app.module.ts:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http';

// Imports for loading & configuring the in-memory web api
import { InMemoryWebApiModule } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import { InMemoryDataService }  from './in-memory-data.service';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HeroDetailComponent } from './hero-detail.component';
import { HeroesComponent } from './heroes.component';
import { HeroService } from './hero.service';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [ 
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        HttpModule,
        InMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(InMemoryDataService)
    ],
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        HeroDetailComponent,
        HeroesComponent,
        DashboardComponent
    ],
    providers: [ HeroService ],
    bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Here is systemjs.config.js:

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },
    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [CHANGELOG](https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md). You need to use the `umd` bundle, and remove it from the `packages`

> In `systemjs.config.js` you should change the mapping to:
>
> ```
> 'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api/bundles/in-memory-web-api.umd.js'
> ```
>
> **then delete from `packages`:**
>
> ```
> 'angular-in-memory-web-api': {        
>    main: './index.js',     
>    defaultExtension: 'js'      
> }
> ```